# Elasticsearch script query get parameter by field value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to filter results with script query. 
I can access parameter values with hardcoded field value like this:

```
"script": "doc['price'].value * params.1000 > 4000",
      "params": {"1000": "1.75"}
```

But if I try to get field value with doc there is no filtering and I can see all results.

```
    "script": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['rate'] > 4000",
      "params": {"1000": "1.75"}
```

Is there any solution to dynamically get parameter value?

EDIT:

The Field 'rate' is just the ID. It is Integer but it is not value I need. The idea is to pass every time different value, via parameter, instead updating field 'rate' frequently. Hope This is better explanation...

example:

```
"script": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['rate'] > 4000",
  "params": {
              "1000": "1.75",
              "1001": "3.75",
              "1002": "5"
            }

if 
'price' == 10 &&
'rate' == 1002
result should be: 10 * 5 > 4000  

if 
'price' == 10 &&
'rate' == 1001
result should be: 10 * 3.75 > 4000

if 
'price' == 7 &&
'rate' == 1000
result should be: 7 * 1.75 > 4000
```

Comment: Is that a string you're trying to access? and what's the filtering you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `rate` as an `integer`, if so shouldn't the script look like such. If I've understood your filtering correctly, if not please correct me:

```
 "script": "(doc['price'].value * doc['rate'].value) > 4000", <--replace params with doc
      "params": {"1000": "1.75"}
```

Comment: doc['rate'].value is integer but it is not value I need. It will change frequently so idea was to pass it as parameter. In this context 'rate' is just ID. I hope this is better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
"script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "doc['price'].value * params.get(doc['rate'].toString()) > 4000",
    "params": {
        "[1000]": 1.75,
        "[1001]": 3.75,
        "[1002]": 5
    }
}
```

Why parameters need square brackets I don't know, but using a script with `Debug.explain(doc['rate'].toString())` shows that the rate field converted to string is like that (perhaps you can use a keyword field for `rate`, in that case I suppose parameters can have the exact same name as the field value):

```
"error": {
    "caused_by": {
        "reason": null,
        "type": "painless_explain_error"
    },
    "class": "java.lang.String",
    "lang": "painless",
    ...
    "script": "Debug.explain(doc['rate'].toString())",
    ...
    "to_string": "[1000]",
},
...
```

I have used `params.get` is because params is an HashMap (again, found using `Debug.explain(params)`). Also parameters values are not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar use case, you can do it like this.

```
"script": {
             "source": "if (params.containsKey(doc['id'].value)) { return params[doc['id'].value] } else { return 0 }",
             "params": {
              "60378": 10.0,
              "50236": 5.0,
              "51233": 3.33
            }
          }
```

Writing an if check before accessing the param value makes it safe query, otherwise it will break with script exception.